# Convert minutes into 100ths of an hour using Excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have a function `=TIME(8,30,0)-(C2-B2)` that work out my timesheet for me but I also need the resulting elapsed time value to be converted into hours and 100ths of an hour.

e.g. *1:45:00* would be *1.75*.

Multiplying the result by 100 and dividing by 60 does not seem to give the desired result.

Comment: What does it give instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time in Excel is a decimal.  so one hour is 1/24th of a full day.  So `1/24`.

Multiply the time by 24 and you will get your decimal:

```
=A1*24
```

[image]